# Summernote + jQuery UI Sortable cannot input text

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, summernote

When I use Summernote and jQuery UI Sortable, I can sort items but cannot input text into the textareas. How can I accomplish it?

#### HTML

```html
<ul class="sortable-list">
      <li>
        <h2>Textarea 1</h2>
        <textarea name="textarea_1" id="textarea_1" class="summernote">
</textarea>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Textarea 2</h2>
        <textarea name="textarea_2" id="textarea_2" class="summernote">
</textarea>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Textarea 3</h2>
        <textarea name="textarea_3" id="textarea_3" class="summernote">
</textarea>
      </li>
</ul>
```

#### JavaScript

```javascript
$('.summernote').summernote();
$('.sortable-list').sortable({
  axis: 'y'
}).disableSelection();
```

Please see also jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L4pq1fad/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer in GitHub issue.

https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1174#issuecomment-115235983

The JS should be:

```javascript
$('.summernote').summernote();
$('.sortable-list').sortable({
  handle: "h2",
  axis: 'y'
});
```

[sanchezzzhak](https://github.com/sanchezzzhak) created jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sanchezzzhak/L4pq1fad/3/